# Window Leaked During Orientation Change on AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

From another class instantiated inside the main activity contains this method that displays an alertdialog. I am still getting the window leaked  during orientation changed. I also checked out several questions, they are getting similar answers.

*Main Class:*

```
AlertDialog aler;
classB(aler);
```

**Class B:**

```
AlertDialog aler2;
classB(AlertDialog a){
this.aler2 = a;
}

private void showWifiDialog(AlertDialog aler2) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
            .setTitle("Device")
            .setMessage("Press OK")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    aler2 = builder.create();

    aler2.show();

}
```

**Experiments:**

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
            if(aler!=null && aler.isShowing())
         {
             aler.cancel();
         }
      super.onPause();
    }

   @Override
    public void onStop(){
        if(aler!= null && aler.isShowing()) {

            aler.dismiss();

          }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(aler!=null)
         {
             aler.dismiss();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this just put this in manifest and try

```
<activity
            android:name="ActivityWhcichCallingDialog"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
/>
```

Comment: As much as possible, I won't use configchanges sir.